# Why can't I install MySQL on my computer?

Tags: windows, mysql

I have read a lot of tutorials, but I am still having problems.

What I tried:

I downloaded mysql-5.5.9-winx64. All that I read says that I can run Setup.exe, but there is no such file in the download. The other option I know there is, is including \mysql-5.5.9-winx64\bin in the `PATH` variable and then trying to execute the `mysql` command. When I do that, the error I get is:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

I then downloaded mysql-5.5.9-winx64.msi, which is easier to install, but once I followed the instructions and it was installed, I got the same error executing the `mysql` command. How can I use MySQL?

EDIT: I've now removed everything I installed, and I want to start from scratch.

Comment: Cross posted on SF - http://serverfault.com/questions/242925/why-cant-i-install-mysql-on-my-computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are experiencing one or more of the following problems:

- the main mysql process is not running when you try to execute queries
- your connection string or credentials are incorrect
- the setup did not complete

Usually, individuals who install MySQL also install Apache as well as a LAMP php/apache server. [XAMPP is super easy and fast](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#641). You can install MySQL individually, or alongside Apache, PHP, etc all at once.

Comment: even if I'm not going to use php at all?? I want to create a web application based on ruby on rails

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the service isn't started.

run services.msc and check if MySQL is listed and what its status is.

You might have it set to 'manual' as well.  Setting it to 'automatic' will fire it up when you start the system up.

That's the exact error I get if I stop the service.

I suppose it could be a firewall issue too, but check the service.